Is our site lacking the migration capabilities of other SE sites?
It seems like we don’t have a flag option to migrate a question to another specific site. Why is that?
I suggested two questions to be migrated; they were declined. Why? Does our site not handle migration robustly?

@user6527 The physics SE is intended for addressing questions that are asked by graduate students in physics, not any basic issues, nor philosophic implications of physics.  That SE would not welcome a mass transfer of physics/philosophy borderline questions.

Most sites do not have selectable migration targets other than their own meta. This is the default. It is "almost never" the case where a selectable migration target is provided to a site. These paths are only created when:

There is a clearly-defined topic that is wholly inappropriate on one site and wholly appropriate on another.

and

That topic is asked about daily on the former site.


+1 Someone sounds like a moderator.
